# SQL RIGHT JOIN not working

Tags: mysql, sql, case, average, right-join

I may probably missing something really obvious, but I cannot get my RIGHT JOIN to work correctly in my SQL statement.

I have a table with the following columns:

id, test_id, score, class_id, rec_date

I wish to get the average score for each class for each test, which is identified by test_id.  I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT c.class_id, 
  ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN s.test_id=1 THEN s.score END),1) AS test1,
  ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN s.test_id=2 THEN s.score END),1) AS test2,
  ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN s.test_id=3 THEN s.score END),1) AS test3
FROM scores s
RIGHT JOIN classes c ON s.class_id=c.class_id
GROUP BY c.class_id
```

I wish to produce null values, even when there are no scores for a class, however this statement only produces data for a class when there are scores present for one or more of the tests.  I believe my problem may lie somewhere with the way I am calculating the AVG with the CASE operator.

Comment: Have you tried the inverse(`LEFT OUTER JOIN`)?

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of the tables and using LEFT JOIN?

Comment: there is absolutely nothing wrong with your query. It works, I tested it. How about looking over your data ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk you were correct, there was a problem with the data in the classes table.  Thank you for your post.

Answer (score 0):

You are aggregating over different sets of rows, so you have to use subqueries in the `SELECT` part. Like this:

```
SELECT c.class_id, 
  ROUND(AVG(SELECT s.score
            FROM scores s
            WHERE s.test_id = 1
              AND s.class_id = c.class_id)) AS test1,
  ROUND(AVG(SELECT s.score
            FROM scores s
            WHERE s.test_id = 2
              AND s.class_id = c.class_id)) AS test2,
  ROUND(AVG(SELECT s.score
            FROM scores s
            WHERE s.test_id = 3
              AND s.class_id = c.class_id)) AS test3
FROM classes c
```